# pylint fixme exclude pattern

Tags: python, regex, pylint

I was hoping to have `pylint` exclude specific patterns of 'fixme' when a bug # is provided (or ultimately any excluding regex would work). The only `miscellaneous` checker option seems to be `notes`. Is this possible? If not, any pointers to what/how to extend would be appreciated.

pylintrc:

`[MISCELLANEOUS]
notes = FIXME,XXX,TODO`

`# TODO: This needs work`

Should produce a warning from pylint

`# TODO: Bug #14 - This needs work`

Should not produce a warning - a traceable Bug # is identified, so it can be tracked there.

Comment: this is currently not possible. You may suggest this feature on pylint's bug tracker : https://bitbucket.org/logilab/pylint/issues (or even better, submit it along with a pull request!)